# jQuery: Problem with windowed controls in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, dialog, shim

I have a web page which contains a select box. When I open a  jQuery Dialog it is displayed partly behind the select box.

How should I approach this problem? Should I hide the select box or does jQuery offer some kind of 'shim' solution. (I have Googled but didn't find anything)

Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>testJQuery</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Rational Application Developer">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/smooth/theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

    <a class="pop" href="nix">Click me</a>

    <p/>

    <select size="20">
        <option>s jl fjlkdjfldjf l*s ldkjsdlfkjsdl fkdjlfks dfldkfjdfkjlsdkf jdksdjf sd</option>
        <option>s jl fjlkdjfldjf l*s ldkjsdlfkjsdl fkdjlfks dfldkfjdfkjlsdkf jdksdjf sd</option>
        <option>s jl fjlkdjfldjf l*s ldkjsdlfkjsdl fkdjlfks dfldkfjdfkjlsdkf jdksdjf sd</option>
        <option>s jl fjlkdjfldjf l*s ldkjsdlfkjsdl fkdjlfks dfldkfjdfkjlsdkf jdksdjf sd</option>
        <option>s jl fjlkdjfldjf l*s ldkjsdlfkjsdl fkdjlfks dfldkfjdfkjlsdkf jdksdjf sd</option>
    </select>

    <div id="xyz" class="flora hiddenAsset">
        <div id="dialog" title="Edit Link">
            <p>Enter the link details:</p>
            <table width="80%" border="1">
                <tr><td>URL</td><td><input id="url" style="width:100%" maxlength="200" value="{url}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Title</td><td><input id="title" style="width:100%" maxlength="200" value="{title}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Target</td><td><input id="target" size="20" maxlength="200" value="{target}"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/firebug/firebug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqSOAPClient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.debug('ready');
        $('.hiddenAsset').hide();

        $('a.pop').bind('click', showDialog);
        console.debug('ready - done');
    });

    var showDialog = function(){
        console.debug('show');
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#666',
                opacity: '.3',
                filter: 'alpha(opacity=30)'
            },
            width: '400px',
            height: '300px',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        console.debug('show-done');
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with jQuery in particular. This is a known bug in IE 6 - Windows-native select boxes always appear on top of other elements. The only thing you can do is hide the select boxes when they're covered up - usually replacing them with something that looks like the select box.

Comment: Yes, I realise this. I had been using mootools and a ui framework from cnet. The ui framwork did something with an iframe when a dialog was opened. The iframe suppressed the select boxes.

Comment: Can you cover up a select box with an iframe? That would be easier than replacing it with a fake select box. Either way it's outside my experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found a plug-in which helps - [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) Strange that it is available as a plug-in. Why isn't it integrated in the main UI?!

Tried it out but, unfortunately, it screws up my dialog! The dialog contents are all shifted left by 30-40 pixels :-( . Next problem...