# Flash Object Upstaging a Pop Up Div

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, flowplayer

We have Flowplayer video player running on the website (via the jQuery method), a Div Pop up with the jQuery UI tools.

The problem is, the Div is being out staged by flowplayer, making the flow player have a higher stack order. Having a look at some of the other forums, there was a solution that I added into my flowplayer code. wmode Transparent.

```
flowplayer("player", "URL", { wmode: "transparent", ... });
```

This works on Firefox, but fails in IE7 and 8. So I added the position and z-index, but IE7 and 8 are showing the Flowplayer upstaging the pop up div. If anyone has had this problem, know how to fix this issue or have something that I may have over looked, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Currently, the Div has the follow:

```
<div ... style="z-index:999; position:relative;"> ... </div>
```

Edit: Even without the Position and z-index, it displays correctly in FF, but not in IE.

Comment: I believe IE7/8 don't support transparency.

Comment: Relative positioning isn't helping much, imo. Try absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you might try to old "IE shim" technique, which consists of sticking an iframe behind your div, forcing IE to give it display precedence.  The following SO page has a link to a jQuery plugin that might make it a bit easier for you:

[jQuery: Problem with windowed controls in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173866/jquery-problem-with-windowed-controls-in-ie6)

Comment: Thanks chprpipr, this seems like a reasonable way to work with IE, I'll bookmark this, because I'm sure something like this will come up again.

I did create a work around by hiding the video when the pop up div is displayed, as they shouldn't be watching the video if the pop up div is shown, and once the div is hidden (closed) then the video will be displayed again.